Demonstrating ties to home country in UK visit visa
Can I use an inheritance will to show evidence of ties to my home country?
I am a student and need to go for a short-study visit visa and am finding it hard to show ties to my home country. Obviously as a student I am financially dependent on my parents, and don't have a job or property or dependents of my own. I am only child too.
This short study lab course of 3 days (I applied for a 6 day visa) is a condition for me to pursue my Bachelors at a UK university and I have a conditional offer letter from them (this being one of the conditions) and a partial scholarship. I am planning to include both of these. I have been studying online with Open University and doing the courses all of which are part of the condition.
I am including sponsorship from my father and his bank statements etc. There is more than 20 times the amount I need for this visit. I have also shown proof that I live in my parents house and proof that they own it.
My previous visa application was rejected because of 2 reasons.

One being that I had only proved my enrollment in the lab school but not the fact that it is a condition or that I have a conditional offer or scholarship. I had also not shown that I am studying 2 of the 5 conditional courses and have completed 2 previously last year.
The second reason was that they couldn't see an intent to return. I had included my mother's bank statement, my birth certificate and a letter from her showing her sponsorship.



In most cases you get en inheritance no matter where you are, and people have been known to give up sums of money, so the inheritance needs to be a large sum with some rather unusual conditions (and you need a lawyer to say whether those hold up, and I'm not a lawyer) attached.

Apply for an education program that is long term then this condition of intent of return and all this won’t apply on you

Unfortunately I see zero probability of UKVI accepting an inheritance will as sufficient proof of ties.

You do not need to be present in your home country (Pakistan, based on the reference to PKR in the refusal letter) to inherit.
You’re demonstrating immigrant intent because your visit purpose is a precursor to plans to study in the UK. Unfair as it may seem, UKVI may well conclude that you would just choose to overstay.
Pakistan is a high risk immigration country.
The UK is tightening up on immigration levels in general, including student routes.


I do need to be present in Pakistan to apply for a student visa (it is stated on their website). Also what if I ask my parents to transfer the property to my name? Would that help?

No, IMHO. Property can be managed from afar, it’s not a compelling reason to leave the UK

So what can a person in my situation do? I mean they have made this just impossible! I wouldn't be able to go the university this way

I would look for another way of fulfilling the conditions to pursue a Bachelors in the UK. For example, completing a lab course in Pakistan, or in another country that you could visit more easily than the UK

Is showing ties to home country a requirement for the student visa as well? Would I be refused that too based on the same circumstances?

Not at all to the same extent. Student visa eligibility/suitability is more about the applicant’s credibility as a student, their ability to support themselves financially etc
